Is there a reason not to declare multiple functions at the same time?
This is my code and I thought this would work, and it actually works.
#include <stdio.h>
void function1(),function3(), function6();

void function1()
{
    printf("Test Function 1 \n");
    function3();
}

void function3()
{
    printf("Test Function 3 \n");
    function6();
}

void function6()
{
    printf("Test Function 6 \n");
}

int main(void) {
    function1();
    return 0;
}

But what I have heared was I should not do like void function1(),function3(), function6(); and instead write one-by-one (told by a professor).
Is there any reason for that? Or is that just some kind odd informations?

Please indent your code correctly, it's very hard to read like so.

Oh sorry I wasn't expected to be like that, fixing now

If you stop using deprecated empty paramter lists, such a long line of function declarations is just unreadable. Isn't that already reason enough to not use it?

https://www.osnews.com/story/19266/wtfsm/

Guys, I am sorry with that. Already fixed. :/

Your title should be "more than 1". Already squeezing 2 declarations in a line is too much.

@Gerhardh Empty paramseter lists are not obsolete, they mean exactly the same thing as (void) since C23.

Alternatively, you could use typedef void fn(void); fn function1, function3, function6; to heavily compress the header file.


Is there any reason for that? Or is that just some kind odd informations?

There is what the syntax allows on one hand, and code style guidelines on another.  The instructions you're asking about fall into the latter category.
Style guidelines are about writing code so that it is easier to read and maintain -- personally, for your team, and sometimes for a wide audience.  It has also become partly about minimizing change sets in source control systems.
Unlike the language's syntax rules, style guidelines do not, in general, enjoy universal acceptance.  Some are more widely accepted than others, and some even conflict with each other, but among the most widely accepted is that only a single function should be declared in each function declaration.  This is much easier to read and maintain than the alternative, especially when the functions are declared with prototypes (as they always should be, for both stylistic and semantic reasons).

In industry as well, one expects documentation to be written for each function declaration, and one would need each function to be on separate lines to do this effectively.

It's about readability and future-proofing.
If you end up wanting to change the prototype of one of the functions (from, say, void to int), your change will end up touching 3 lines of code instead of just 1.

So is it only about those two, readability and for future? I was told that that is the WRONG way, and I was confused. I understand that may make some issues later on, Is there any "wrong" reason for not to use that?

@SJang "Only those two" is some misjudgement. Besides the rules defined by the standard, there is hardly something more important than readability and maintainability. Only in very rare cases performance requirements might prevent a readable version but as in your case, most of the times, readability does not reduce performance in any way.

void function1(),function3(), function6();

This works when the return type is void. Were you to return a pointer instead, this doesn't work
int* function1(),function3(), function6();  // possible bug here

because the type is "propagated", but the * is not. So instead you have to write
int* function1(), *function3(), *function6();

Does this now look like a good idea? Or does it look "wrong", like the teacher said?
